# Login validation asp.net mvc identity 2.0 with 3 login attempts before lockout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Not sure how best to post this, but it is to **save anyone else** from hours of searching trying to set up login validation using asp.net mvc identity 2.0

The code below works, but if anyone else can improve on it please do so and save others from hours of searching.

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //*******************************************************
                // Check if email exists, if not no point in continuing
                //*******************************************************
                var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // var checkIfUsernamePasswordValid = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email,model.Password);

                    //*******************************************************
                    // As password is hashed, need to use line below to return success
                    //*******************************************************

                    var checkIfUsernamePasswordValid = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.PasswordHash, model.Password);

                    //*******************************************************
                    //To stop user from login in before email is confirmed, use line below
                    //*******************************************************

                    var emailIsConfirmed = await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id);
                    if (!emailIsConfirmed)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Please check your email inbox and verify email address before trying to login"));
                        return View();
                    }

                    //*******************************************************
                    // Check if user is locked out due to invalid login attempts,
                    // If they are inform them
                    //*******************************************************

                    if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Your account has been locked out for {0} minutes due to {1} invalid login attempts.", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout"]));
                    }

                     //*******************************************************
                     // Count number of failed login attempts and display to user
                     // Before locking them out
                     //*******************************************************

                    else if (await UserManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id) && Convert.ToBoolean(checkIfUsernamePasswordValid) != true)
                    {
                        await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);

                        string message;

                        if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
                        {
                            message = string.Format("Your account has been locked out for {0} minutes due to {1} invalid login attempts.", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout"]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int accessFailedCount = await UserManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);

                            int attemptsLeft = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout"]) - accessFailedCount;

                            message = string.Format("Invalid email/password. You have {0} more attempt(s) before your account is locked out for {1} minutes.", attemptsLeft, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan"]);

                        }

                        ModelState.AddModelError("", message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                        // If user get login correct before lock out reset failed count
                        await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Sorry we cannot find your email address."));
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

On final last step, in the `public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)`

its automatically logs the user in, if you want to prevent that, comment out the following line.

```
await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
```